# Java check that string will only allow commas as special chacters

Tags: java

how can I check to make sure the only special character a string can have is a comma?

```
testString = "123,34565,222"  //OK

testString =  "123,123.123." //Fail
```

Comment: a regex like [a-zA-Z0-9,] ?

Comment: Define "special" - what _exactly_ do you want to allow and forbid?

Comment: I thought it was pretty straight forward...only allow a comma...in additional to #'s and letters....hence my example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A full working example based on @Simeon's regex. This reuses a single `Matcher` object, which is recommended if the check will be done frequently.

```
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class OnlyLettersDigitsCommas  {

   //"": Dummy search string, to reuse matcher
   private static final Matcher lettersCommasMtchr = Pattern.
      compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9,]+$").matcher("");

   public static final boolean isOnlyLettersDigitsCommas(String to_test)  {
      return  lettersCommasMtchr.reset(to_test).matches();
   }

   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      System.out.println(isOnlyLettersDigitsCommas("123,34565,222"));
      System.out.println(isOnlyLettersDigitsCommas("123,123.123."));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java OnlyLettersDigitsCommas
true
false
```

Comment: Yes a single `Matcher` is definitely better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a quick `String.contains` method like this:

```
if ( testString.contains(".") {
    // fails
}
```

But I would consider using Regex for this type of validation.

EDIT : As stated in the comments of the question : `[a-zA-Z0-9,]`

Comment: that just checks for "."

Comment: Yeah I think I need to use regex

Comment: Oh, yeah, oops I didn't see the you wanted to check for everything. You have a comment with the right answer on your question.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a

```
if (!testString.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9,]+$")) {
        // throw an exception    
}
```

check ?

Comment: does that not just check it contains those chars, rather than does NOT contain anything else?

Comment: hmm, I haven't tested it, hence the maybe, but I will now, the OP was not too clear on the question

Comment: @Brian: I don't understand. I've reread the question, and it seems like this is a good regex for it.

Comment: I think all you need are the ^ and $ anchors then it's good, as per aliteralmind's answer, and the + to match one-or-more

Comment: @aliteralmind - yes the basic regex is good, just not sufficient, as you've identified yourself in your answer

Comment: Ahhhh!! There *must* be a plus in the regex, or this will always evaluate to false...unless the string happens to be exactly one character. But since it's `matches`, you *don't* need the `^` / `$` anchors, although I like to put them anyway.

Comment: No you need the anchors too. Otherwise the first substring to meet its criteria (one or more of these chars) hits the "pass" button. The anchors effectively tell the matcher the whole string must consist of only these chars.

Comment: @Brian: Incorrect: Both [`Matcher.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) and [`String.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))) implicitly use those anchors, as they either matches, or do not match, *the entire string*. It is redundant to use to put `^` and `$` in the regex. I like doing so, however, as a matter of style (and as insurance against accidentally changing `matches` to `find`, for example).